# How to write script that website users can add to their website header for added functionality

Tags: javascript, firebase

I am new to this type of development so i dont know the right words to use. I need to know what would be my starting point if i want to create a script that extends website functionality and set it up as a pay to use script. an example of what im talking about is Jivochat. to get it working on your site you simply put a script in your header of your site. And some how it gets all the css and hides all the sensitive data.

I know javascript but im not sure how to make all of this work in just one line of code like how they did it.

How do i begin to learn what that is? what is it anyway?

Comment: what do you mean by `hides all the sensitive data` - what data? why is it sensitive? what does it have to do with functionality of the script?

Comment: @JaromandaX what i mean by sensitive data is the user doesnt see any of the database calls and they dont have access to any of the files that make up the extra feature, all they can see is their own token or key. Im sorry i dont know the name of it or how to word it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're looking for is writing a third-party app. Here's a book that could get you started: https://www.manning.com/books/third-party-javascript.

The gist of the setup:
- you deliver a small script tag a client will add to their site
- that script loads a js file from your site with your app code and runs it when it loads
- that script generates an iframe to render an app hosted from your domain.

It doesn't have to be exactly like that, but that's a common setup.

Comment: Thank You! Thanks to you i know what they are called and where to go to learn how to build them!